# Is there a way to follow a windows fileystem shortcuts programatically in C# without using COM?

Tags: c#, windows, shortcut

Back in .NET 1.0 days I wrote a method to return the target of a shortcut on MS Windows.  It did this through using an interop to the Windows Script Hosting Object Model and brute forced through the COM interface:

```
private FileInfo GetFileFromShortcut(FileInfo shortcut)
{
    FileInfo targetFile = null;

    try
    {
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell wShell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShellClass();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShortcut wShortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShortcut)wShell.CreateShortcut(shortcut.FullName);

        // if the file wasn't a shortcut then the TargetPath comes back empty
        string targetName = wShortcut.TargetPath;
        if (targetName.Length > 0)
        {
            targetFile = new FileInfo(targetName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { // will return a null targetFile if anything goes wrong
    }

    return targetFile;
}
```

This still bugs me, and I was looking to replace this with something more elegant, but only if the replacement actually works at least as well.  I still can't find a native C# way of finding the target of a shortcut.  Is there one, or is this still the best way of doing this type of thing?

Comment: Great question. Have not thought about how to get this working without COM interop

Comment: I couldn't avoid using the shell via unmanaged code to achieve this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has written a class to manipulate shortcut files in C# called [ShellLink](http://vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp), but it too uses COM.

Comment: Hiding the COM activity behind another layer wasn't really what I wanted to do - I want to publish this code into an open source project and didn't like the COM bashing part.  But if there's no other way....

Comment: Why don't you want to use COM? Usign IShellLink is the correct way to do things as that is the API that Windows provides for shortcut parsing/moditifcation. Your original code which used Windows Scripting Host wasn't the best way to do things but that was because it used a wrapper object designed for scripting languages, not because it used a COM object. COM is used behind the scenes all the time on Windows; it's unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just open the .lnk or .url file and parse it?

This talks about the same thing and shows what the files look like:
http://www.programmingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=7335

Comment: I'm not sure that parsing a file that hasn't a published definition is something that I want to rely upon in my production code.  There is a safe workaround which is bashing the COM interface at at least I know that will always work.

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in this as well a while ago.

Here is the accepted [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425969/general-approach-to-reading-lnk-files) with a link to a (informal) [description of the format](http://www.stdlib.com/art6-Shortcut-File-Format-lnk.html) of LNK files. Apparently, all available methods *yet* go through some API.