# General approach to reading lnk files

Tags: language-agnostic, shortcut, lnk

Several frameworks and languages seem to have lnk file parsers (C#, Java, Python, certainly countless others), to get to their targets, properties, etc. I'd like to know what is the general approach to reading lnk files, if I want to parse the lnk in another language that does not have said feature. Is there a Windows API for this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use lnk file parser at *J.A.F.A.T. Archive of Forensics Analysis Tools project*.

See lnk-parse-1.0.pl at http://jafat.sourceforge.net

There seems no have no dependencies.  Syntax is simple and link file becomes a simple text in standard output and to be usable on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[@Giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441399/4575793): Actually, there **is** an official specification of lnk files, at least [it is claimed so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305%28PROT.10%29.aspx).
However, for some reason, the link seems to be dead, and after downloading the whole (45 MB) doc package (`Application_Services_and_NET_Framework.zip`), it appears that it does not include the file `MS-SHLLINK.pdf`.

But is this really surprising ?

Once you got the file format, shouldn't be too hard to write code to read it.

Comment: Now this is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

Answer (score 0):

Using ***WSH-related components*** seems the most convenient option to read `.lnk` files in most languages on a post-XP windows system. You just need access to the COM environment and instantiate the `WScript.Shell` Component. (remember that on win, references to *the Shell* usually refer to `explorer.exe`)

The following snippet, e.g. does the thing on PHP: *(PHP 5, using the COM object)*

```
<?php
$wsh=new COM('WScript.Shell'); // the wsh object

// please note $wsh->CreateShortcut method actually
// DOES THE READING, if the file already exists. 
$lnk=$wsh->CreateShortcut('./Shortcut.lnk');
echo $lnk->TargetPath,"\n";
```

This other one, instead, does the same on VBScript:

```
set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut("./Shortcut.lnk")
MsgBox lnk.TargetPath
```

Most examples in the field are **written in VB/VBS**, but **they translate well** on the whole range of languages supporting COM and WSH interaction in a form or another.

[**This simple tutorial**](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbscript/l/blvbscriptintro.htm) may come handy, as it lists and exemplifies some of the most interesting properties of a `.lnk` file other than the most important: `TargetPath`. Those are:

- `WindowStyle`,
- `Hotkey`,
- `IconLocation`,
- `Description`,
- `WorkingDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

here's some C# code using the Shell32 API, from my "ClearRecentLinks" project at https://github.com/jmaton/ClearRecentLinks

To use this your C# project has to reference c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll

```
            string linksPath = "c:\some\folder";
            Type shell32Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
            Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shell32Type);
            Shell32.Folder s32Folder = (Shell32.Folder)shell32Type.InvokeMember("NameSpace", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { linksPath });
            foreach (Shell32.FolderItem2 item in s32Folder.Items())
            {
                if (item.IsLink)
                {
                    var link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)item.GetLink;
                    if (link != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Target.Path))
                    {
                        string linkTarget = link.Target.Path.ToLower();
                        // do something... 
                    }
                }
            }
```