# Is this possible to get a SHARE .lnk target?

Tags: php, windows, shortcut, network-shares

I'm working on a php project in an entreprise with some Windows WebServers. My problem is that I don't know how to read a target of a SHARE .lnk shortcut with PHP.

I can read a target of a .lnk shotcut like this one: 'C:\Users\LoL'.

But I can't get a target of a .lnk shotcut like this: '\\server\share\dir'.

Do you know any php function that allow me to read this target?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem.

The best solution that I found to read a share .lnk shortcut with a target like this ''\server\share'' is the ***COM object***.

From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core. You have to add COM support in php.ini:

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

To read the target of a share .lnk shortcut in PHP, you have to use the follow instructions:

```
<?php

    // create the object
    $wsh = new COM('WScript.Shell');

    // $wsh->CreateShortcut method READS, if the file already exists. 
    $lnk=$wsh->CreateShortcut('ShortcutPath.lnk');

    // show the target
    echo $lnk->TargetPath,"\n";
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

I let you some sources that helped me:

- [Class 'COM' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found)
- [General approach to reading lnk files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425969/general-approach-to-reading-lnk-files?rq=1)